# Add OpenGL support to a previously built OpenCV build

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, cmake

I'm trying to improve the performance of my code by replacing

```
cv::namedWindow("Display frame", WINDOW_NORMAL);
```

with

```
cv::namedWindow("Display frame", WINDOW_OPENGL);
```

I get the following error after making that change:

```
No OpenGL support (Library was built without OpenGL support) in cvNamedWindow, file C:\tmp\opencv32\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp, line 764
```

So now I know that my OpenCV build doesn't support OpenGL. I've seen numerous solutions of how to build OpenCV with OpenGL support. But I don't want to rebuild OpenCV because it's part of a bigger SDK I'm using and the configuration options for the current build are very specific. It would be much easier for me to just somehow add the support for OpenGL to the current build. Is this possible, and how?

UPDATE: I looked at the CMakeLists.txt files that were used to build the top level SDK. The CMakeLists.txt file for the openCV folder that came with the SDK looks like this:

```
# Add target for OpenCV
add_library(OpenCV INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(OpenCV INTERFACE opencv-3.2/include)
set(OPENCV_LIB ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/opencv-3.2/library)
target_link_libraries(OpenCV INTERFACE
    ${OPENCV_LIB}/opencv_core320.lib
    ${OPENCV_LIB}/opencv_highgui320.lib
    ${OPENCV_LIB}/opencv_imgcodecs320.lib
    ${OPENCV_LIB}/opencv_imgproc320.lib)
file(GLOB OPENCV_DLL "opencv-3.2/binary/*.dll")
file(COPY ${OPENCV_DLL} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release)
```

I'm not too familiar with CMake, so please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this means that the prebuilt SDK contains already built openCV and the CMakeLists.txt is simply adding the already built openCV library to the final SDK build. Now, with this information, is there a way to add openGL support?

Comment: But you'll have to build at least some of the files.

Comment: @Zindarod I'm fine with rebuilding some files if necessary, I'd prefer to keep the current build as intact as possible

Comment: Have you enabled the `WITH_OPENGL` option with `ccmake` and run make again? See how much it changes the build. Obviously make a copy of your OpenCV folder before doing this.

Comment: @Zindarod I'm not sure if I can do that. I've updated my question with some new information.

Comment: You can build a fresh copy of OpenCV 3.2.0 on your machine and replace the required files in your SDK with the new ones. And the `/include` folder as well.